# Swift - Merging 2 arrays of objects with a key

Tags: swift, class, merge

I'm new to Swift programming and been working on an app fir a couple of weeks now, and I'm stuck at a crucial moment in the development.

I'm fetching data from a URL that returns a JSON. It is decoded and the data o is stored in an array.

I do the same thing with another URL.

Now I'm trying to initialize my final object wich will be a combination of 2 objects contained in each of the arrays.

Each array is a dictionary and each objects has a property call `id`.

I can't figure how I can go through each arrays to check for the `id` of each objects to match and then initialize a new object by combining the data from each object (look at the code below, it will make more sense hopefully)

I tried a `for` ... `in` but I couldn't access the `id` property and compare it. I tried to do a  `for` ... `in` inside a `for` ... `in` to compare the `id` value: no success too.

On top of this, the initialization is also a challenge. I tried to implement something like this:

```
 self.mergedList = (//result of the loops).map(MergedViewModel.init)
```

Here an example of the 2 objects

```
class MergeInformationViewModel {
    var id = "1234"
    var information = "This Is My Name"
}

class MergeDataViewModel {
    var id = "1234"
    var data = "Some very important data"
}
```

The object I'm trying to initialize

```
class MergedViewModel {

    let mergedViewData: MergeDataViewModel
    let mergedViewInformation: MergeInformationViewModel

    init(data: MergeDataViewModel, information: MergeInformationViewModel) {
        self.mergedViewData = data
        self.mergedViewInformation = information
    }

    var id: String {
        return self.mergedViewData.id
    }

    var information: String {
        return self.mergedViewInformation.information
    }

    var data: String {
        return self.mergedViewData.data
    }

}
```

Finally the class handling the initialization. I'm working on a SwiftUI project

```
class MergedListViewModel: ObservableObject {

    init() { mergingAndInit() }

    @Published var mergedList = [MergedViewModel]()

    var mergeInformationList = [MergeInformationViewModel]()
    var mergeDataList = [MergeDataViewModel]()

    func mergingAndInit() {


        //...


    }
}
```

the final result would look something like this

```
class MergedViewModel {
    var id = "1234"
    var information = "This Is My Name"
    var data = "Some very important data"
}
```

How can I implement the `func mergingAndInit()` into my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the `merge(_:uniquingKeysWith:)` is not applicable, Xcode is returning an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out!

```
        for mergedI in mergeInformationList {
            for mergedD in mergeDataList {
                if mergedI.id == mergedD.id {
                    self.mergedList.append(MergedViewModel(data: mergedD, information: mergedI))

                }
            }
        }
```